# How can I create RTC Build Definitions and Build Engines with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, build-automation, rtc

I am trying to configure a Build Server with the Jazz-based Rational Team Concert(RTC) for a distributed team already using RTC 3.0.1. Documentation is often confusing as it tends to be Eclipse based. This article (https://jazz.net/library/article/119) refers to a nonexistent Package Explorer. Other articles state that I may build with the Jazz Build Engine, of which I haven't found any downloads. Rational Build Forge is mentioned for a price, but I hope to do this as close to free as possible. 
In summary my scenario is:

- An RTC server with the source code repositories.
- A Build Server with Visual Studio 2010 and the Rational Team Concert Client for Eclipse
  IDE (version 3.0.1)
- Several developers using the RTC Visual Studio client successfully.

Can anyone point me to the correct documentation for this particular scenario?

Comment: Both [the eclipse instructions](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/tcreatebuilddefinition.html) and [the visual studio instructions](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/topic/com.ibm.team.concert.dotnet.doc/topics/t_create_builddef.html) start with "In the Eclipse client", so I am assuming that creating build engines/definitions isn't possible with the Visual Studio JTS plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- using [BuildForge](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/RationalBuildForge) (RTC [knows how to integrate with it](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/BuildFAQ#How_does_Jazz_Team_Build_interop), but Build Forge isn't free. See "[Enterprise Build Solutions with Build Forge and Rational Team Concert 3.0](https://jazz.net/library/article/607)").
  See "[Rational Team Concert 3.0 and Build Forge: An integration scenario](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/BuildFAQ#How_does_Jazz_Team_Build_interop)".
- using Team Build (part of RTC), which includes a Jazz Build Engine (JBE) that pulls requests from a build definition queue to build these configurations.
  The limits of TeamBuild: once you begin to make your Ant scripts larger and more difficult to debug or want to choreograph your software delivery life-cycle with several phases of activities within the same project, you will likely want to use Build Forge to accomplish these types of enterprise-level automation goals.

You can start with Team Build and the [Jazz Build Engine](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/t_build_overview.html) you can even [define several on one machine](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/BuildFAQ#MultipleJBEs), to avoid processing all the Build jobs in sequence only).
You can install it [following this page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_install_build_toolkit.html), and accessing the "[all downloads page of your RTC version](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/3.0.1.1?p=allDownloads)": look for a "Build System Toolkit".

None of this is specific to Visual Studio, but if you can start a build with TeamBuild, you can then check how [Visual Studio integrates with the builds](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/features/vsclient#vs-4).